# Как в wordpress с rewrite получить с url blabla?sub=xxx переменную в странице

Tags: php, wordpress

не программист и сложно сформулировать мысль
суть такова: мне надо, что бы у человека при переходе по ссылке blabla.ru/telefon?sub=+72384234235 в тексте было сообщение и внизу ссылка типа link где этот телефон подхватывался из url запроса

Comment: [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: все не плохо, но в wordpress с mod_rewrite не заводится

Comment: Уточните что там у Вас не заводится

Comment: на вордпресс не перехватывает параметр из url. могу заплатить, лень возиться

Comment: Значит следовало сразу идти туда, где можете заплатить.